# Android Studio Gradle Hangs during loading old gradle project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Recently, I came across a problem in my android studio. I was using older version of Gradle in my old lapi. And recently I bought a new lapi, and installed latest version of android studio, hence the latest gradle.

Now I came across a serious problem. I was not able to load my previous gradle build projects in my new lapi. When I tried to load my old gradle projects in my new lapi. Android studio just hangs during opening old projects. Only option left in that case was to `End Process` my `Android Studio`. Howsoever when I started to create  new  project it was working fine and reloading the project made no issue.

I was really frustrated what was causing this.
I came to conclusion that my old projects were using old gradle hence they were responsible to make my android studio hangs during startup of loading them. Basically android studio was trying to find old gradle version if not able to find it. It will automatically try to download it from internet. But that may consume too much of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's How I solved the issue without downloading the older version of `Gradle`.

Say, We have old project named `MyOldApplication`
Open android studio and start a new project (Say `MyApplication`).

now open the directory where this `MyApplication` project is created.

Simple copy following files from `MyApplication`
(`build.gradle`,`gradle.properties`,`gradlew`,`gradlew.bat`,`local.properties`)

And folder named `gradle`

Now go to the folder where `MyOldApplication` and simply replace these files.

Now visit every sub folder where project files `build.gradle` files resides.(Ex : `app`,`library` ... etc)

and simply replace these lines

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.1.0"

targetSdkVersion 24
```

NOTE: replace these values with the same as found in `MyApplication` build.gradle file (found inside MyApplication\app)

Now simply open this project in the android studio.

It will ask the project to update to latest gradle.(Press OK).

Yay!! You are done.

Comment: *build.gradle* - better not - you should change only what is need to change ,
*gradlew ,gradlew.bat* - what for? it just run gradle wrapper, *local.properties* - android studio will fix it ... *gradle.properties* no need for this ... for changaing the gradle version the only file you need to change is ... `gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`

Answer (score 0):

first delete the `gradle` folder then open the project, it will upgrade the `gradle wrapper` in `gradle.properties` file in `gradle/wrapper` folder